# What are fs.chunks and fs.files in lab cloud

Tags: mongodb, heroku, server, parse-server, mlab

I am saving data to mlab storage but I ran out of data, so I went into my account and realized that I had 490mb worth of data in fs.chunks. Can I delete fs.chunks and fs.files class. Or will something very bad happen. Im very confused by these two classes so more clarification would much be appreciated. Do I need fs.chunks and ds.files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These collections are created when an application is storing data in a database using [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs-collections).

In general, its much more efficient to store files in a file storage service such as AWS S3 and storing references to the files in the database, as opposed to storing the files directly in the database.